# app($classModel)->getQuery() != app($classModel)->query() or app($classModel)->getQuery() != $classModel::query()

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, builder

Why is function **getQuery()** diferance to **query()** in model?

```
app($classModel)->getQuery() != app($classModel)->query() or app($classModel)->getQuery() != $classModel::query()
```

In this example model1 is diferance to model2, why?

```
$model1 = app($class)->query()->first();
=> App\Models\User {#3389
 id: 1,
 name: "laisha88",
 first_name: "Jackson",
 last_name: "McKenzie"
}
$model2 = app($class)->getQuery()->first();
=> {#3369
 +"id": 1,
 +"name": "laisha88",
 +"first_name": "Jackson",
 +"last_name": "McKenzie"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you trying to do or what you want?

Comment: Yes, my question is already better, is it clear?